# Why isn't the projection of points (shapefile) aligning with the raster file in R plot?

Tags: r, plot, raster, projection, shapefile

I am trying to align points from a shapefile with the center of landscapes from a raster file in R for downstream landscapemetrics analyses. The files were extracted from the same project in qgis (where they were perfectly aligned) and despite having the same crs, when I plot the files in R it would seem that one of the files is slightly rotated.

[Plot of unaligned points and raster](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VnLFV.png)

I have tried to use the st_transform function to rotate the points by a few degrees counter-clockwise by playing with the +towgs84 settings, but I only seem to shift the all of the points left/right or up/down.

An example of what I tried:
`pCH_rotate <- st_transform(pCH, "+proj=somerc +lat_0=46.95240555555556 +lon_0=7.439583333333333 +k_0=1 +x_0=2600000 +y_0=1200000 +ellps=bessel +towgs84=0,0,0,-200,200,0,0 +units=m +no_defs")`